# If argument isn't a file, then read from stdin

Tags: c, if-statement

I have a program that takes command line arguments, checks if they are files, if they are, then do something, if not, do something else.

The basic structure I have looks like this

```
for (i=1;i<argc-1;i++){
    if ((fp=open (argv[i],"r"))==NULL){
        #Do blah blah
    }
    else{
        #do blah blah
    }
}
```

But for some reason, when my argument isn't a file, instead of doing blah blah, it returns an error saying that it isn't a directory or file. Is there something wrong with my if statements?

Comment: Perhaps you want to use [`fopen`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen) instead? `open` expects an `int` as its second argument, not a string.

Comment: Suspect you want `for (i=1; i<argc; i++){`, not `-1`.

Answer (score 3):

The [`open()`](http://codewiki.wikidot.com/c%3asystem-calls%3aopen) system call will return a negative value if there was a problem, so `fp` technically won't be `NULL`.

Also, as stated in @Kninnug's comment, open expects an int as its second param, so you would want `O_RDONLY` instead of `"r"`

Try chaning it to

```
if((fp=open(argv[i], O_RDONLY))==-1)
```

Or, go with @Kninnug's suggestion and use `fopen()`. If you do, you will need a `FILE *` pointer instead of an `int`.

Comment: Also: `open` expects an `int` as its second parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Your file name would be in argv[1]. So instead of `for (i=1;i<argc-1;i++){` you should have `for (i=1;i<argc;i++){`
`

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if ((fp=open (argv[i],"r"))==NULL)
```

To

```
if((fp=open(argv[i],"r"))==-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Checking if argument is a path to a file and attempting to open a file are 2 different things.  There are lots of reasons why `fopen()` fails, but the argument is a legitimate file name.

To see if an argument is a file, use `stat()`.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h> 

int isfile(const char *path) {
  struct stat buf;
  int retval = stat(path, &buf);

  // A pedantic approach would also check the `errno`.
  if (retval) return 0;

  switch (buf.st_mode & S_IFMT) {
    case S_IFREG: return 1;
    // Maybe other cases could return 1 depending on OP's needs.
  }
  return 0;
}
```